# Installing TWRP on locked Sony Z3 Compact D5803

Tags: adb, root-access, twrp, device-firmware, flashtool

I was googling that for ages and couldn't find any decent solution.

I have locked Sony Z3 Compact [D5803] and I need to install TWRP and backup the current OS.

I CAN use flashtool to install custom files that had been downloaded from xperiFirm but it seems like impossible mission to root it afterwards :)

I was also trying this article here :

https://forum.xda-developers.com/z3-compact/general/recovery-root-mm-575-lb-t3418714

...without any success.